# How do you convert a vector of vectors containing doubles in C++ to a matrix in R using the Rcpp library?

Tags: c++, r, matrix, vector, rcpp

I am using the Rcpp library to convert a vector of vectors containing doubles in C++ to a matrix in R. I essentially want to call this function and have it return a matrix to me in R. However, in both methods, the console prints "error: vector".

My first method to convert is using the wrap function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix returnRetrieval(string fileName){
//bm.real_psi is a globally declared vector of vectors
return Rcpp::wrap(bm.real_psi);
}
```

My second method is creating a new matrix and returning that to the R code.

```
//also tried this and same error occured
Rcpp::NumericMatrix createMatrix(vector< vector <double> > input){
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix storeContainer(input.size(), input[0].size());
  for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <input[0].size(); j++){
      storeContainer(i, j) = input[i][j];
    }
  }
  return storeContainer;
}
```

This is a little frustrating, so if anyone can help out, it would be much appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, this is how I've accomplished this in the past (although I did it with an `IntegerMatrix`):

```
NumericMatrix res(input[0].size(),input.size());
double* resp = REAL(res);
for (size_t ci = 0; ci < res.ncol(); ++ci)
    std::copy(input[ci].begin(),input[ci].end(),resp+ci*res.nrow());
return res;
```

[`std::copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) should be maximally efficient, I think.

Comment: What does the "NUMERIC(res)" signify? I've been getting errors on my console relating to that.

Comment: @AdiSidapara Sorry, I used the wrong macro. It should be `REAL()`. The macro retrieves a raw pointer to the underlying vector data.